# Python function to extract multiple segments of a file path

Tags: python, string, filepath

I would like to write a Python function that is capable of taking a file path, like:

> /abs/path/to/my/file/file.txt

And returning three string variables:

- `/abs` - the root directory, plus the "top-most" directory in the path
- `file` - the "bottom-most" directory in the path; the parent of `file.txt`
- `path/to/my` - everything in between the top- and bottom-most directories in the path

So something with the following pseudo-code:

```
def extract_path_segments(file):
    absPath = get_abs_path(file)
    top = substring(absPath, 0, str_post(absPath, "/", FIRST))
    bottom = substring(absPath, 0, str_post(absPath, "/", LAST))
    middle = str_diff(absPath, top, bottom)

    return (top, middle, bottom)
```

Thanks in advance for any help here!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are looking for [`os.sep`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.sep), together with various `os.path` module functions. Simply split the path by that character, then re-assemble the parts you want to use. Something like:

```
import os

def extract_path_segments(path, sep=os.sep):
    path, filename = os.path.split(os.path.abspath(path))
    bottom, rest = path[1:].split(sep, 1)
    bottom = sep + bottom
    middle, top = os.path.split(rest)
    return (bottom, middle, top)
```

This does *not* deal very well with Windows paths, where both `\` *and* `/` are legal path separators. In that case you *also* have a drive letter, so you'd have to special-case that as well anyway.

Output:

```
>>> extract_path_segments('/abs/path/to/my/file/file.txt')
('/abs', 'path/to/my', 'file')
```

Comment: Can't `"\"` or `"/"` be used as a path separator on windows?  I don't think that this will work in that case ... (although, I'm willing to not work on windows ;-)

Comment: @mgilson: Yes, windows accepts both, but `os.sep` is always `\\`. That's a pain, so I've defined `sep` as a keyword argument that defaults to `os.sep`.

Comment: Quoth [the `os.sep` docs](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.sep): "*Note that knowing this is not sufficient to be able to parse or concatenate pathnames — use os.path.split() and os.path.join() — but it is occasionally useful.*"

Comment: @lazyr: Lucky for me, on windows you'd also have to content with the drive letter at the start, which the OP didn't specify how to deal with, so I'll just ignore the Windows case. :-)

Comment: fails when path has less than 3 '/'

Comment: @Satvik: at which point the definition of a top, middle, bottom is ambiguous at best already. Better to fail than to second-guess, then.

Comment: @lazyr, using os.path.split() and os.path.join() doesn't even make the code all that more complicated

Answer (score 3):

use `os.path.split`:

```
import os.path

def split_path(path):
    """
    Returns a 2-tuple of the form `root, list_of_path_parts`
    """
    head,tail = os.path.split(path)
    out = []
    while tail:
        out.append(tail)
        head,tail = os.path.split(head)
    return head,list(reversed(out))

def get_parts(path):
    root,path_parts = split_path(path)
    head = os.path.join(root,path_parts[0])
    path_to = os.path.join(*path_parts[1:-2])
    parentdir = path_parts[-2]
    return head,path_to,parentdir

head,path_to,parentdir = get_parts('/foo/path/to/bar/baz')
print (head)        #foo
print (path_to)     #path/to
print (parentdir)   #bar
```

Comment: Conforms with recommmendations in docs? Check. Cross-platform? Check. This is the way to do it. It should be noted that `get_parts` requires absolute and normalized paths as argument (e.g. `/abs/path/to/my/file/subdir/../file.txt` will fail) and that it does not handle windows network mount points (`\\server\share\abs\path\to\my\file\file.txt`), but those problems are [easily](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.abspath) [amended](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.splitunc).

Answer (score 2):

Using `os.path.split()` and `os.path.join()` as we are supposed to

```
>>> import os
>>> pth = "/abs/path/to/my/file/file.txt"
>>> parts = []
>>> while True:
...     pth, last = os.path.split(pth)
...     if not last:
...         break
...     parts.append(last)
...
>>> pth + parts[-1]
'/abs'
>>> parts[1]
'file'
>>> os.path.join(*parts[-2:1:-1])
'path/to/my'
```

As a function

```
import os

def extract_path_segments(pth):
    parts = []
    while True:
        pth, last = os.path.split(pth)
        if not last:
            break
        parts.append(last)
    return pth + parts[-1], parts[1], os.path.join(*parts[-2:1:-1])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> p = '/abs/path/to/my/file/file.txt'
>>> r = p.split('/')
>>> r[1],'/'.join(r[2:-2]),r[-2]
('abs', 'path/to/my', 'file')
```